# Logstash File plugin fails on UTF-8 JSON input

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8, logstash

We import JSON log files into an Elasticsearch database, and at least on some machines we've discovered that import fails complaining about encoding problems ("incompatible encodings: Windows-1252 and UTF-8"). The input configuration is simple:

```
  file {
    path => "D:/Octopus/Applications/prod-ndoa/Bridge.Web/logs/BridgeSoap.*.txt"
    sincedb_path => "D:/Octopus/Applications/prod-ndoa/Bridge.Web/logs/sincedb"
    codec => json
   }
```

But as long as input files contain byte origin mark (BOM) in the beginning of the file, the processing fails.

If I remove codec json, then the import works but using "plain" format (i.e. our JSON documents are imported as strings).

What is strange is this has been working for quite some time on some machines. It's the test of a new machine installation that uncovered this error.

Answer (score 1):

According to Logstash folks, this is a know issue with Ruby parser that is used by JSON codec:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-json/issues/1

Unfortunately on Windows machines UTF-8 documents are usually saved with BOM in the beginning of the file, so it would be great if the JSON code was more flexible and accepted these characters.